# How to create nested GraphQL fields with Sangria's `@GraphQLField` annotation

Tags: sangria

I have a simple `case class MyContext(queries: Query)` that I provide to the schema with : `sangria.schema.Schema(deriveContextObjectType[MyContext, Query, Unit](_.queries)`

`MyQuery` is a trait of `Query`

```
trait MyQuery {
  @GraphQLField
  def item(ctx: Context[MyContext, Unit])(id: String) ... 
}
```

This works great. But what if I want to nest resolvers?

```
query { 
   item { 
     status # status is resolved from source B
     price # price is resolved from source C
   }
 }
```

Is that possible to achieve? Would I return an `ObjectType[Item]` that  has properties `status` and `price` annotated with `@GraphQLField`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `deriveObjectType` for an `Item`. It is also able to handle the `@GraphQLField` annotation (as an alternative you can also use `IncludeMethods` macro setting). Here is an example:

```
implicit val ItemType = deriveObjectType[MyContext, Item]()
```

Answer (score 1):

Really appreciate [@tenshi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604181/3384225) answer! I tried using the `deriveObjectType` but was getting a type error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : sangria.schema.Context[MyContext,Item]
 required: sangria.schema.Context[MyContext,Unit]
```

But using `deriveContextObjectType` in conjunction with `AddFields` is working:

```
def schema = sangria.schema.Schema(
    deriveContextObjectType[MyContext, Query, Unit](_.queries,
      AddFields(
        Field(
          name = "item",
          fieldType = deriveContextObjectType[MyContext, Item, Unit](_ => new Item),
          resolve = _ => ()
        )
      ))
    )
```

And the Schema looks good, yielding:

```
type Query {
  item: Item!
}
```